# How to print from second row after match?

Tags: awk

I have an input

```
text and numbers
 name of section

      72.01043451      0.013887  0.8416
      64.76001571      0.015442  0.8556
```

I want to print $1

```
/  name of section/ { in_f_format=1; next}
(in_f_format & FNR==2) {print($1)}
```

gives empty row and that $1
How to write print from second row?

This is syntax error

```
/  name of section/ { in_f_format=1; next}
(in_f_format & FNR==2) {print($1)}
```

two next doesn't work.

Thank you

Desired output:

```
  72.01043451
  64.76001571
```

Comment: You need to replace `&` with `&&`, but I don't know what you're exactly trying to achieve. `FNR==2` is already specifying that only the 2nd line will be printed. If you're looking for the 2nd line after the pattern, that's a different story and you should not use `FNR==2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk '/name of section/ { line = FNR + 2 } line != 0 && FNR >= line { print $1 }' file
      72.01043451
      64.76001571
```

Here we detect the pattern and set the variable `line` to the line that we'd like to print from (`FNR + 2` means "this line plus two"). If we've reached the indicated line, we print.

Comment: This is more succinct and admittedly should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intention correctly,

```
/  name of section/ { c=FNR;}
(FNR-c>=2 && c>0) {print $1}
```

If the pattern is matched, `c` is set to the current line number, then if `FNR` is equal to or greater than `c+2`, which is the 2nd line after the line that the pattern is matched, print the first field. Without initialization, `c` is zero, so we want to avoid that the 2nd line of the whole file be printed and therefore add an extra condition `&& c>0`.

Comment: Thank you and this print only one row? I ment all row except the empty row

Comment: Up to what? The end of the file? The next time the pattern is matched?

Comment: Yes to the end of the file

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you and how to keep restriction of area after name of section? I am sorry I have forgotten to write that there is text and numbers before

Comment: It should work with text and number before. I tested. If you have a specific file that doesn't work, edit it into the question.

Comment: Yes it works with text I added but not with file I added to my question, I don't undestand why. Thank you

Comment: Should be fine now.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and worked fine

```
awk '/name of section/{x=NR+3}(NR<=x){print}' l.txt | awk 'NR>2{print $1}' filename
72.01043451
64.76001571
```